# SetWindowsHookEx - antivirus issue

Tags: winapi, antivirus

The task I have to do is to disable windows docking from keyboard shortcut
(VK_RWIN or VK_LWIN + arrow) in a single application.

To do this, I've decided to compelately block VK_RWIN and VK_LWIN virtual buttons in this app.
I've used SetWindowsHookEx with LowLevelKeyboardProc callback.
I'm checking if my application is activated via WM_ACTIVATEAPP message.
Inside the callback, if the application is active, I'm checking virtual keys and return 1,
when VK_RWIN or VK_LWIN is pressed.
Works perfect, just as expected.

Now, I just wonder if antiviruses may detect such usage as malware?

Comment: This is probably a little too broad.  Nobody knows all the heuristics for all the popular anti-malware apps.  Hooking other apps could certainly be considered suspicious.  Hooking only your own process probably shouldn't be suspicious, but who knows if all the anti-malware apps catch that nuance?  It seems very odd to want to disable this functionality.  The desktop window manager just turns it into a size and move operation on the window, which the user can do anyway.

Comment: And what if the application is digitally signed?

Comment: Signing an application may or may not modify an AV behaviour. From my own experience I can only tell you that it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely. A lot of AV software (maybe most) will flag your application as malware simply because it contains a call to SetWindowsHookEx. For example, I have some code that creates keyboard hooks and I have to exclude that directory from the AV scanner because otherwise it quarantines my app as soon as I build it. That has been true of all three AV products I've used in recent years.

And since every AV product has its own way of whitelisting applications, it will be very difficult for you to figure out in advance what users will have to do to use your application.

Answer (score 0):

Digitally sign your application so that AV software doesn't get triggered on it.